# Symfony 4, How to load third party libraries from vendor folder

Tags: symfony, orm, symfony4, idiorm

I am trying to load a third party library called [Idiorm](https://packagist.org/packages/j4mie/idiorm) but I can't seem to get it to work. I installed it via composer like this `composer require j4mie/idiorm`. The library has been installed in the vendor folder. I can see it loaded in the `autoload_static.php`  like this

```
public static $classMap = array (
    'Collator' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/symfony/intl/Resources/stubs/Collator.php',
    'IdiormMethodMissingException' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/j4mie/idiorm/idiorm.php',
    'IdiormResultSet' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/j4mie/idiorm/idiorm.php',
    'IdiormString' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/j4mie/idiorm/idiorm.php',
    'IdiormStringException' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/j4mie/idiorm/idiorm.php',
    'IntlDateFormatter' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/symfony/intl/Resources/stubs/IntlDateFormatter.php',
    'Locale' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/symfony/intl/Resources/stubs/Locale.php',
    'NumberFormatter' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/symfony/intl/Resources/stubs/NumberFormatter.php',
    'ORM' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/j4mie/idiorm/idiorm.php',
    'SqlFormatter' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/jdorn/sql-formatter/lib/SqlFormatter.php',
);
```

I can't give it a custom namespace as it is a third party library. So how do I install it correctly so that I can start using it in my controllers

Comment: you can create your own bundle, that uses this library as dependency to integrate it to symfony right way (https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles.html), but why don't you use doctrine orm?

Comment: @PavelAlazankin Thank you I will read on that. Our senior developers have decided to use Idiorm ORM instead.

Comment: @PavelAlazankin I have created a bundle but how do I import the `vendors/j4mie/idiorm.php` file. include and require hasn't worked.

Comment: i took a look at this library and i'm not sure now that you really need separate bundle for this as it is really simple. so why can't you use it in your controller? I just tried and it just works

Comment: I added `use ORM;` in use-section and then inside of action I configured connection with `ORM::configure(...)` like it is said in documentation and the got some data from database with `$product = ORM::for_table('product')->where('id', '1')->find_one();` (http://idiorm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying.html)

Comment: @PavelAlazankin Thanks. that actually worked. I thougt I cannot use `use` unless a namespace has been defined, Great work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, really simple issue once a package is downloaded via composer in my case `composer require j4mie/idiorm` you can literally start "use"ing it. No pun intended

in my Model Class

`use ORM`.....